# How I may break lines in given String, and push formatted String into the List?

Tags: android, string, list, kotlin

Let's say, that I have String, that contains data (it comes like that from api response). I'd like to break lines in it, and pass it to the ArrayList as a single string, so it can be displayed later on. I'd like to have something like:

1 - api response gives a string = "2020-01-01"

2 - convert this string, to break lines where dashes are =

```
2020
01
01
```

3 - myList.add(convertedString)

4 - display.

Comment: You meant split the string by char '-' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.replace(Char, Char)`:

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
val string = "2020-01-01"
val convertedString = string.replace('-', '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string using `split` method then do what you want to do with splitted parts.

```
String string = "2020-01-02";
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 2020
String part2 = parts[1]; // 01
String part2 = parts[2]; // 02


String formattedString = part1+"\n" +part2+"\n" +part3;

output: 2020
        01
        02
```